# Is there now no logical "OR" operator with the new search engine?

Tags: feature-request, support, search, elasticsearch

A lot of people were unhappy that the old search defaulted to `OR`, and I agreed.

With the change of Stack Exchange's search engine it now defaults to `AND` and [everybody is happy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/160101#160101).

But actually sometimes I do want to use `OR`. There's plenty of concepts that can be expressed in different ways or with different vocabulary. In these cases I like to use `OR` between synonyms:

> - `url OR uri schema OR protocol`
> - `seek OR fseek`
> - `options OR prefs OR preferences OR settings OR config`
> - `folder OR dir OR directory`
> - `parameter OR param OR argument OR arg`

I've tried `or`, `OR`, and `|` but none seem to work. Nothing is mentioned under "Advanced Search Tips".

(I'm tagging `support` in case it's there but I can't find it and `feature-request` in case it's not there.)

Comment: I think the problem with both systems is that it is not obvious how to mark terms optional or required, or how weighting works.  I was expecting `-term` for forbidden and `+term` for required, but that doesn’t quite seem to work.  I think the forbidden may work though.

Comment: Otherwise a single argument like ORQUERY (or any other words) would be nice to copy former behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero search results when searching for \[tagOne\] \[or\] \[tagTwo\] score:-2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165251/zero-search-results-when-searching-for-tagone-or-tagtwo-score-2)

Comment: @BethWhitezel Not a duplicate; that one's just about tags, while this one is about all search terms.

Answer (score 5):

I got zero results doing the search `[php] or [mysql]`, and realized that the Advanced Search Tips don't say how to do an 'OR' search (and also I found the Search Page referenced in the FAQ is no longer there).

I found the following situations:

1. For doing `tag only` searches you can use `[php] [or] [mysql]`
2. <strike>For word searches you can use `php or mysql`</strike>
3. For phrase searches (with quotes on words) I couldn't get either to work, if you use single quotes, then it seems like you actually get an 'and' search

**Could we please have a definitive explanation or doing OR searches in SE?**

Comment: shouldn't that mean that "php or FakeWordThatNoOneWillEverWriteInAQuestion" should return all question with php in the text? Just tried it and returned 0 results, so I fear number 2 is wrong.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, hmmm, looks like I was wrong, have edited.

Comment: BTW, just tried **"php [or] FakeWordThatNoOneWillEverWriteInAQuestion"** and that doesn't work too

Answer (score 5):

According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165251/zero-search-results-when-searching-for-tagone-or-tagtwo-score-2#comment482399_165251) there isn't a way to do this.  Apparently the search engine never handled it.

Answer (score 2):

Another case in which OR doesn't seem to work is the `user:` operator.

Searching [user:1 OR user:2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1+OR+user%3A2) only finds posts by user 2 and says «results found containing **or** search options **user 2**». Apparently the "redundant" operator is just ignored.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to limit your search scope well enough (say: within a single tag) you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Here is a query to get you going:

[Search for 3 OR terms in the Body of posts within a tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1604541/search-for-or-terms-in-a-tag?tag=python&term1=for&term2=stream&term3=loop&opt.withExecutionPlan=true)