# Zero search results when searching for [tagOne] [or] [tagTwo] score:-2

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-search

I'm able to search for the newest questions tagged with [xcode] *and* [ios] *and* score >= -2.

[image: [xcode] AND [ios]]

But I see 0 results when searching for the newest questions tagged with [xcode] *or* [ios] *and* score >= -2.

[image: [xcode] OR [ios]]

Comment: I'm not sure it's the correct syntax for an OR search. Even without the `score`, `[xcode] or [ios]` [yields nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D+or+%5Bios%5D). Also, in your screenshot, `[or]` looks like a tag to me. But I cannot find any documentation about the OR operator. (It seems to me that, if not recognized as an operator, `or` is also an ignored word, just like `a`, `an`, `is`, `on`, `the`, and a zillion more.)

Comment: Ah, indeed `[or]` [used to be the supported syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2/87802#87802). Not anymore, it seems?

Comment: Is there a new supported syntax for using the advanced search features (like `score:` or `answers:`) in conjunction with [tagOne][or][tagTwo]? For now, I'm using [/questions/tagged/tagOne%20or%20tagTwo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagOne%20or%20tagTwo), but I'd like to include advanced search features like `answers:0`.

Comment: (I left a comment for the developers about OR [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/why-or-operator-by-default-in-search/161776#161776).)

Comment: @Arjan - the `[or]` was never intentionally supported, and it *never* worked except in the explicit `[tag] [or] [tag2]` case, no other operators could be used.  It's an artifact of how the redirect to `/questions/tagged` works, not the search engine...the search engine never handled it.  That's not to say we won't support an "OR" tag syntax, it's on my todo after this NY move...along with 50 other items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update:* OR tags is now supported, it requires an explicit `or` between one or more tags, anything without an `or` in between is AND (the historical default).

For example: [[xcode] or [ios] score:-2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D+or+%5Bios%5D+score%3A-2)

---

*Original answer:*
This is currently working as-designed, the `[or]` syntax was never designed to work...and it never *did* work when combined with anything else.  It worked simply because the redirect logic never checked for it (still doesn't).

That being said "or" for tags is something I'll try and get to after our colo move to NY (hopefully this coming weekend).  It's no longer technically an impossibility on the back-end, it's now just a matter of syntax and parsing.