# A button to view questions that have my favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

I have tried to search if someone has already posted a question like this.
Not having found anything I try to ask my second question on Meta.

It is possible to have a button (like the All Questions button) that shows only the questions marked with (the current user) favorite tags?

For example, if I have marked as favorite the tags C#, VB.NET, WinForms, Net etc... I really wish to have a single button (possibly between the Questions and Tags header buttons that shows the questions that have these tags.

Comment: Have you looked at [tag filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/)? Not exactly what you are looking for, but it's pretty close.

Comment: @Yannis thank, I didn't know of this feature. Could you point me to some docs/faqs where I can learn how it works? I have tried to build a filter, but I can't find the way to use it on stackoverflow

Comment: @Steve Just select `stackoverflow` in the `just these sites` option and put something like `[javascript] [or] [html]` (filter by [tag:javascript] or [tag:html]) in the `Just questions tagged with the ... tag`

Comment: @WouterJ I have done that, but then? Can I go back to SO site and use that filter somewhere? It seems that it works only when I am on the main stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Wouter J says, you can also create a bookmark to a query matching any of the tags on which you are interested.

When writing such query on the query box, use the `or` operator: `[tag1] or [tag2]`

The resulting link will be something like:
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+vb.net+or+winforms+or+.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#+or+vb.net+or+winforms+or+.net)

Comment: I think you can only use the `[or]` operator: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87802/177764

Comment: Currently both work (at least with simple queries for alternative tags), but it seems that `or` is preferred http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166159/212755

Answer (score 1):

We already have this feature. It's on the [stackexchange website](https://stackexchange.com/) (the base website of the SE network).

Go to the [filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) and click on 'Favorite Tags' in the sidebar. This will show you all questions which has your favorite tags on all SE websites.

You can also get email updates for your favorite tags. Just click on the 'Email Updates' section in the sidebar for more information.

Comment: Good, but this has a drawback. 'on all SE websites'. For example, `Windows` in superuser.com and on SO are for two completely different kind of questions. If I am interested only on Programming questions I have to use filters (and I have not quite figured out how to make them persist)