# Why does this search not return expected results?

Tags: support, search

I was searching for this post:

- [Please Join Us in Welcoming Our New Meta Stack Exchange Moderators!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318630/please-join-us-in-welcoming-our-new-meta-stack-exchange-moderators)

I searched the following:

```
body:moderator OR body:nominated OR body:nomination is:q closed:no score:100..500
```

i.e.:

- The post either contains 'moderator', 'nominated' or 'nomination'
- It is a question
- It is not closed
- It has a score between 100 and 500

The only result returned was:

- [Introducing the Moderator Council - and its first, pro-tempore, representatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347104/introducing-the-moderator-council-and-its-first-pro-tempore-representatives?r=SearchResults&s=1|27.6783)

Why was the intended post not returned?

It contains 'moderator' and satisfies all the other criteria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OR` operator is [only supported for tags, not for keywords](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). Stack Exchange's search functionality isn't as extensive as Google's.

> #### OR operator
>
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": [widgets] or [geegaws] returns questions tagged with either tag.

You can tell this by looking at how [the query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3Amoderator+OR+body%3Anominated+OR+body%3Anomination+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+score%3A100..500) is parsed:

[image]

As a workaround, perform three separate searches:

- `body:moderator is:q closed:no score:100..500`
- `body:nominated is:q closed:no score:100..500`
- `body:nomination is:q closed:no score:100..500`

Answer (score 6):

The search engine doesn't seem to support the OR operator for body searches:

> @Arjan - the [or] was never intentionally supported, and it never worked except in the explicit [tag] [or] [tag2] case, no other operators could be used. It's an artifact of how the redirect to /questions/tagged works, not the search engine...the search engine never handled it. That's not to say we won't support an "OR" tag syntax, it's on my todo after this NY move...along with 50 other items. – Nick Craver♦ [Jan 27 '13 at 18:57](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165251/zero-search-results-when-searching-for-tagone-or-tagtwo-score-2#comment482399_165251)

Since I haven't seen any feature requests for an OR operator tagged status-complete since then AND the advanced search help only talks about using this OR operator for tags, I feel safe claiming that since [Please Join Us in Welcoming Our New Meta Stack Exchange Moderators!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318630/please-join-us-in-welcoming-our-new-meta-stack-exchange-moderators) doesn't include the words *nominated* or *nomination*, it's not included in your results.