# Allow ORing between more search terms like `inquestion:123`, or at least tell me the search failed

Tags: feature-request, bug, search

I just tried to look at two sets of answers, for different question:

I've tried using `inquestion:12791 OR inquestion:11422` the [result](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A12791+OR+inquestion%3A11422) of which ignores the first search term.

I've tried using `(inquestion:12791) OR (inquestion:11422)` the [result](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%28inquestion%3A12791%29+OR+%28inquestion%3A11422%29) of which gives no posts.

The issue in the first attempt is the same for other terms, like `lastactive:`, so if I tried (silly example, bear with me): `lastactive:2012-04-03 or lastactive:2012-04-10 or lastactive:2012-04-17 or lastactive:2012-04-24` I only get the results of `lastactive:2012-04-24`.

Currently this only works for tags, based on the edit to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168433/175002).

I'd like this functionality if there's no big overhead (so I appreciate you probably won't want to go re-indexing, or rebuilding the search engine), but if not an error message would be appreciated to fix the underlying bug.

---

I'm tagging as both [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) as it's **one issue** that can either be improved with a new features, or at least have the bug resolved. There is at least one [previous request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163557/is-there-now-no-logical-or-operator-with-the-new-search-engine) related to this, but I'm also suggesting that this is a bug that should be fixed. Also that question is old and outdated, and with no useful answer, shouldn't be used as a duplicate target for this one.

---

p.s. the reason I was looking in the first place is to see if there's a way of finding all my questions answered by a particular user ([like so](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A12791%20user%3A3136)). If there's another way of doing this, I'm happy to hear about it but that's not why I posted right now.